# Why do convex curves with sharp edges automatically flatten?

Tags: modeling, edges

I've been making a few weapons for a short while now and I've found that a similar issue arises pretty commonly. This time I've noticed that when making a convex portion of a blade with an edge that sharpens to nothing, the curvature is lost and somehow flattened prematurely.

The blade is two-sided but there should be no clipping faces, I've already merged vertices and tried remaking the faces. I know that making more edges to join the outer and the inner vertices can resolve this, but it doesn't preserve the smooth look of the blade. I also noticed that this problem doesn't arise when only one side of the sword has the face that's causing the issue.
This is blender 2.8

[image: Sword Edge]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because the surface is pretty much undefined. The only guaranteed flat surface there is is between exactly three vertices. If you have more vertices without edges,  it's a guessing game for Blender, so it will come to different conclusions, depending on angle and other factors.

What you can try is using the subdivision surface modifier, simple, not cattmull-clark, in a high resolution. It will try to fill the face with edges.

Comment: Would it not also work to go from Edit Mode to Mesh > Clean Up > Split Concave Faces? How might these two options produce different results?

Comment: 1.: This would probably create edges between the vertices which define the curves, which would lead to an "edgy" look, which OP specified they didn't want. 2.: Modifiers are nondestructive, you can turn them on and off as you go, so OP could keep their current workflow.